# Laravel Eloquent check on previous eager load relation

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have some trouble with chaining relationships. I want to chain three of them, but this is not working properly:

```
return UserModel::with('cars.pieces.attributes')
```

I must check not only on pieces for the attributes but on the result given by cars.pieces. I must know both pieces and cars to give the good attributes

I want to retrieve a user with the cars he chose then the pieces of the car and the attributes of these pieces. All of those things are chosen by the user.

With only `cars.pieces.` I have my user, then the array of cars then the array of pieces for this car. When I add attributes, I have attributes not for pieces of cars of users but attributes for pieces whatever cars it is.

It seems like the relationship is only looking for the previous relation and not the whole packet.

UserModel.php

```
public function cars(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(CarsModel::class, 'user_cars', 'id_user','id_cars');
}
```

Then in CarsModel.php

```
public function pieces(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(PiecesModel::class, 'cars_pieces', 'id_cars','id_pieces')
}
```

And finally in PiecesModel.php :

```
public function attributes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeModel::class, 'user_cars_pieces_attributes', 'id_attribute', 'id_piece')
}
```

The last entity is using 4 fields for the primary key :

```
id_user, id_car, id_attribute, id_piece
```

My relation is probably something like this :

[image]

What could be a way to retrieve attributes for pieces of cars for the user?

Thank you for helping!

EDIT : I have an idea to do that. I can just retrieve pieces of cars and then for each pieces I check for their attributes based on where clause with both id_pieces and id_cars then combine to my original array but it would be not efficient imo

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you swapped the foreign keys around in the `attributes()` function. It should be:

```
public function attributes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeModel::class, 'user_cars_pieces_attributes','id_piece', 'id_attribute');
}
```

Secondly, you're not specifying on which models you defined each of the relationships, but you might rather want to use `hasMany`. For example, does a user belong to many cars (then use `belongsToMany` as you currently do) or does a user have many cars, i.e. many cars belong to a user (then use `hasMany`)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited to specify models where I define relationships. I accidentaly swapped but it was good in my code. I think that by where I'm defining each relations this is ok to use belongsToMany. The problem is that I can't define a relation not only base in ONE key but TWO keys, or an alternative to do that if Eloquent can't support this.